# Select Multiple Values from different columns

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have 5 different columns with over 100 rows each having an assortment of numbers.

I have been able to count all values from column 1 that equal 3

I want to be able to count all the number 3s from all 5 different columns and add them

```
$countquery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PowerBall WHERE W1=3";
$countresult = mysql_query($countquery) or die(mysql_error());

while($countrow = mysql_fetch_array($countresult)) {
    echo "<br />";
    echo "There are ". $countrow['COUNT(*)']."-3s";
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the total number of 3 values in all of your columns.

```
Select
  sum(case when col1 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol1,
  sum(case when col2 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol2,
  sum(case when col3 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol3,
  sum(case when col4 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol4,
  sum(case when col5 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol5
from PowerBall
```

If you want this in one column, then you can use:

```
select TotalCol1 + TotalCol2 + TotalCol3 + TotalCol4 + TotalCol5
from
(
  Select
    sum(case when col1 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol1,
    sum(case when col2 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol2,
    sum(case when col3 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol3,
    sum(case when col4 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol4,
    sum(case when col5 = 3 then 1 else 0 end) TotalCol5
  from PowerBall
) src
```

Or even:

```
select sum(Total)
from
(
  Select count(col1) Total
  from PowerBall
  where col1 = 3
  union all
  Select count(col2)
  from PowerBall
  where col2 = 3
  union all
  Select count(col3)
  from PowerBall
  where col3 = 3
  union all
  Select count(col4)
  from PowerBall
  where col4 = 3
  union all
  Select count(col5)
  from PowerBall
  where col5 = 3
) src
```

Comment: you don't need a CASE statement, SUM(COL1=3) will suffice since it's already a boolean and will evaluate to either 1 or 0.

Comment: @KevinNelson I use `CASE` because it is ANSI standard SQL. The `SUM(COl1 =3)` is MySQL specific syntax. :)

Comment: Whats the TotalCol1 does it calculate or is it a variable

Comment: @inVINCEable Those are the alias names for each of the columns created.  The `as` is optional.

Comment: `TotalCol1` references the `SUM` calculation from the derived query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COL1 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Col1',
SUM(CASE WHEN COL1 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Col2',
....
 FROM PowerBall WHERE W1 is not null
```